# Opensource framework to create gmail/google group/facebook kind of interface (and some functionalities)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, cakephp

I am starting a new opensource project. This will be a web app with modern `layout/functionalities`. I want this app to work like `gmail/facebook/google` group.. or some other google products. I want to load all the `js/css` and other assets only one time and load part of pages using ajax request.

I want to use PHP (maybe cakePHP, jQuery). I know how to create this kind of app from scratch, but i am looking for some kind of opensource framework which will help me to not create everything from scratch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a php framework called Elgg (http://www.elgg.org/) which is a php framework designed for social networking based applications.